# Rules for SNAPSHOT versions in Maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, release-management

The site

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html

states

> If a version contains the string “-SNAPSHOT,” then Maven will expand
>   this token to a date and time value converted to UTC (Coordinated
>   Universal Time) when you install or release this component.

Is this literally true in the sense that not only the usual examples of `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` behave like a SNAPSHOT version, but also something like `1.2.3-RC-SNAPSHOT` or `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-RC`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that every version ending with `SNAPSHOT` will be replaced with the date/time value converted to UTC.

---

This transformation is done inside the class [`SnapshotTransformation`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/7e2d657fa08bff3d7f9383bdbb0cb660aec58a11/maven-compat/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/repository/legacy/resolver/transform/SnapshotTransformation.java#L136) of the Maven source code:

> ```
> String newVersion = snapshot.getTimestamp() + "-" + snapshot.getBuildNumber();
> version = StringUtils.replace( baseVersion, Artifact.SNAPSHOT_VERSION, newVersion );
> ```

What is considered a SNAPSHOT version can be seen in the class [`ArtifactUtils`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/ArtifactUtils.java#L35-L50): this code considers that a version is a SNAPSHOT version if its version ends with `"SNAPSHOT"` ignoring case. For this case, [the code also](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/ArtifactUtils.java#L59) adds a dash before the SNAPSHOT if it is not already there.

So, judging from the source code, the book is partially right: it should be "ends with" instead of "contains".